# jquery ajax bad_url error on local machine in same parent folder

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox

Just started learning jQuery so do not know much about the deep mechanics such as errors.

I am using jQuery to parse an xml file for a html page my folder structure is structured in the following way

Client

```
   -CurrentFiles
     -test.xml
   -stations
     -test.html
```

I am using the jQuery cdn by Google to load the jQuery library.

This is my code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var data = [];
        $(document).ready(function () {
           $.ajax({
               type:'post',        //just for ECHO
               dataType: "xml", // type of file you are trying to read
               url: './../CurrentFiles/test.xml', // name of file you want to parse
               success: parse, // name of the function to call upon success
               async:    false,
               error: function(xhr, status, error) { 
                   alert("error");

                   console.log(error);
                   console.log(status);
               }
           });

           function parse(xmldata) {
               $(xmldata).find("value").each(function(){
                   alert($(this).text());
                   data.push($(this).text());
               });
           }
               console.log("data array:" + data);
        });

    </script>
```

The xml file is formatted in the following way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<values>     
  <value date="2015-07-12">37.170</value>
  <value date="2015-07-13">7.190</value>
  <value date="2015-07-12">37.170</value>
  <value date="2015-07-12">3.210</value>
  <value date="2015-07-12">37.20</value>
```

The error I am getting is

> DOMException [NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: "Access to restricted URI denied"
>   code: 1012
>   nsresult: 0x805303f4
>   location: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js:4]

I am not really understanding this error is it on my side that a file could not have the write permissions or is it dealing with the cdn?

By the way I am using firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop locally in FF3 by modifying the security permissions. You can do this by following these steps:

```
Type about:config into the Location Bar (address bar) and press Enter
Click the “I’ll be careful, I promise” button
Change the security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy:
```

True
Local documents have access to other local documents in the same directory and in subdirectories, but not directory listings. (Default)

False
Local documents have access to all other local documents, including directory listings.